# Unknowing odoo Data base logout issue

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo, odoo-9

Database logout unnecessarily and trying to login once again it give error:email/password is wrong in odoo/postgresql.(i noted down the email and password) and these fields are can't be wrong.
i made a changes in inherited sale module report.xml file(qweb)

```
<strong t-field="company.partner_id" style="font-size:18px;"
   t-field-options='{"widget": "contact", "fields": ["name"]}'> </strong>
```

to

```
<strong t-field="company.partner_id" style="font-size:20px;"
   t-field-options='{"widget": "contact", "fields": ["name"]}'></strong>
```

when i revert back original code tried login once but not at all logging into database. help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you must have mistyped your password when you changed it, the change in  your qweb view is not related.

The solution is to log in to your postgre database directly and change your admin password using this SQL command:

```
UPDATE res_users SET password='your-new-password' WHERE id=1;
```

Comment: i already said that noted down all the details, have 3 database which is giving same type of error.problem is occur when do changes in odoo settings for customization of report.